# Why is my worker disabled

Tags: antminer

When looking at my dashboard, it says my worker's state is disabled. I'm using an old S1 (which I know isn't profitable, just playing around) but it is hashing around 176 Gh/s per day.

Comment: Dashboard on what service? Regardless, this is an issue with that particular service, you should contact their customer support.

Comment: Sorry, this is on Slush Pool.